PDF with Fadings and Transparencies Does Not Upload Properly
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament, tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\definecolor{BrooklynBlue}{RGB}{33,41,88}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myborder, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.6cm]
    \node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
    \node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
    \node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
    \node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mytext, color=transparent!0]
    \node (n) at (current page text area) {\swabfamily{\scalebox{2.75}{Uploading Problem}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \fill[BrooklynBlue] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
        \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which produces the output

However, when I upload the PDF as an email attachment, I get---

I suspect the problem has to do with the transparencies and fadings that are included in the PDF output.
QUESTION: What can be done in order to be able to upload the first image as an email attachment and have it appear similarly when opened?
Thank you.

I believed that nothing problem in the code, please zipped the PDF file and send it as attachment and check

well which PDF viewer do you use to view the PDF? A PDF previewer from your email program? Then it is quite possible that it doesn't know fadings.

@UlrikeFischer I uploaded the image to both a Gmail account and a Protonmail account with the same effect. I'm not sure which viewer is used in each case.

if you view the attachment in an external viewer, you can check if the appearances are a function of the viewer or the attachment. or you can download the attachment and compare directly with the original using e.g. cmp.  but the latter test might fail if the file is altered in irrelevant ways. in general, browser/email viewers don't seem as capable of reliable rendering as their standalone counterparts.

The file should not be changed when uploading it to some mail platform. As stated above, it is due to the (different) software that you use when viewing the file.

Perhaps there is a way to do this directly in LaTex, but the following does alleviate the problem: Upload the PDF to an external PDF converter; in this case, I converted the output from the above code to a PNG --- sent it to my email as an attachment and opened it up. A copy of the result is as follows:

